# HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized error in mvc login page

Tags: c#, asp.net

HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.

I am getting this error from last 2 days on my personal laptop as well in office PC. Actually i am trying to execute an DotNetOpenAuth Providr application on my PC but when i try to execute it from VS2012 IDE it fails with HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized his error but when i publish this app to my local IIS it execute fine without any error. I have checked following things.
1) provided full access to folder on disk
2) try with defaultProxy disabling

following is my web.config file

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/729387/HTTP-Error-401-2-Unauthorized-error-in-mvc-login-p

Comment: You forgot to include your web.config file.

Comment: @maheshpardeshi, What was the solution? I am running into same issue with VS 2017